# From double to time with centiseconds - using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So, I'm analysing some data that do not have time and I need to add it.
The original data is like this:

```
+--------+-------+
| Packet | Value |
+--------+-------+
|    196 | 0.631 |
|    197 | 0.742 |
|    198 | 0.981 |
|    199 | 0.874 |
|    ... |   ... |
|    296 | 0.641 |
|    297 | 0.761 |
|    298 | 0.312 |
|    299 | 0.767 |
|    ... |   ... |
|    396 | 0.612 |
|    397 | 0.651 |
|    398 | 0.431 |
|    399 | 0.981 |
|    ... |   ... |
+--------+-------+
```

And the desired output is:

```
+--------+-------+---------------+-------------------+--------------+
| Packet | Value | Duration_Hz   | Duration_Second   |   Duration   |
+--------+-------+---------------+-------------------+--------------+
|    196 | 0.631 |           100 |              0.01 | 00:00:00:00 |
|    197 | 0.742 |           100 |              0.01 | 00:00:00:01 |
|    198 | 0.981 |           100 |              0.01 | 00:00:00:02 |
|    199 | 0.874 |           100 |              0.01 | 00:00:00:03 |
|    ... |   ... |           ... |               ... | ...          |
|    296 | 0.641 |           100 |              0.01 | 00:00:01:00 |
|    297 | 0.761 |           100 |              0.01 | 00:00:01:01 |
|    298 | 0.312 |           100 |              0.01 | 00:00:01:02 |
|    299 | 0.767 |           100 |              0.01 | 00:00:01:03 |
|    ... |   ... |           ... |               ... | ...          |
|    396 | 0.612 |           100 |              0.01 | 00:00:02:00 |
|    397 | 0.651 |           100 |              0.01 | 00:00:02:01 |
|    398 | 0.431 |           100 |              0.01 | 00:00:02:02 |
|    399 | 0.981 |           100 |              0.01 | 00:00:02:03 |
|    ... |   ... |           ... |               ... | ...          |
+--------+-------+---------------+-------------------+--------------+
```

Basically `Duration` is the cumulative duration of the entire file.
Logic:
Each packet has a size of 1Hz, so, 0.01s.

Your help here will be very precious to help creating the `Duration` column.

I'm totally new into Pandas, and from my understanding it's possible to use a Rolling Window.
So since we know the cadence is at every 100packets, the logic and so far what I've done was :
-1: understand how many intervals the entire dataset has

```
# because DF is sorted by PacketCounter, we can get the first packet and last one
firstMoment_fps = df_all_data.head(1)['PacketCounter'].values[0]
lastMoment_fps = df_all_data.tail(1)['PacketCounter'].values[0]
nr_intervals_needed = abs((firstMoment_fps - lastMoment_fps)//100)
nr_intervals_needed
12
```

Then, I calculate the the beginning of each interval:

```
interval = 0
intervals = []
start = firstMoment_fps

# print(str(start) + '^' + str(interval))
while start < lastMoment_fps:
    nextMoment = start + 100
    if nextMoment < lastMoment_fps:
        start = nextMoment
        interval = interval + 1
        #print(str(start) + '^' + str(interval))
        intervals.append(start)
    else:
        break
```

output:

```
[12737, 12837, 12937, 13037, 13137, 13237, 13337, 13437, 13537, 13637, 13737]
```

-2: Then I build a DF:

```
intervals_final_mapping = pd.DataFrame(columns=['From', 'To', 'Value'],
data=[
    [intervals[0]-101, intervals[0] - 1, 0],
    [intervals[0]-1, intervals[1] - 1, 1],
    [intervals[1]-1, intervals[2] - 1, 2],
    [intervals[2]-1, intervals[3] - 1, 3],
    [intervals[3]-1, intervals[4] - 1, 4],
    [intervals[4]-1, intervals[5] - 1, 5],
    [intervals[5]-1, intervals[6] - 1, 6],
    [intervals[6]-1, intervals[7] - 1, 7],
    [intervals[7]-1, intervals[8] - 1, 8],
    [intervals[8]-1, intervals[9] - 1, 9],
    [intervals[9]-1, intervals[10] - 1, 10],
    [intervals[10]-1, intervals[10]+99 , 11]
])

df_all_data['Second'] = ''
df_all_data['Second'] = df_all_data['PacketCounter'].map(intervals_final)
```

The output is

```
+--------+-------+---------------+--------------------+---------------+
| Packet | Value | Duration_Hz   | Duration_Second    | Duration_Main |
+--------+-------+---------------+--------------------+---------------+
|    196 | 0.631 |           100 |              0.01  | 0             |    
|    197 | 0.742 |           100 |              0.01  | 0             |    
|    198 | 0.981 |           100 |              0.01  | 0             |    
|    199 | 0.874 |           100 |              0.01  | 0             |    
|    ... |   ... |           ... |               ...  | ...           |    
|    296 | 0.641 |           100 |              0.01  | 1             |    
|    297 | 0.761 |           100 |              0.01  | 1             |    
|    298 | 0.312 |           100 |              0.01  | 1             |    
|    299 | 0.767 |           100 |              0.01  | 1             |    
|    ... |   ... |           ... |               ...  | ...           |    
|    396 | 0.612 |           100 |              0.01  | 2             |    
|    397 | 0.651 |           100 |              0.01  | 2             |    
|    398 | 0.431 |           100 |              0.01  | 2             |    
|    399 | 0.981 |           100 |              0.01  | 2             |    
|    ... |   ... |           ... |               ...  | ...           |    
+--------+-------+---------------+--------------------+---------------+
```

As we all see, I'm far from the desired output. I've chosen a hard path, and a wrong one.
Could you please help me refine the strategy?

(After this I'll probably create more topics, since this is half of the desired output)

Thank you!

I've chosen a wrong path. I know it's possible to use a Rolling Window, possibly combined with `cumsum` function. Goal is to sum `0.01` values formatting it to a timestamp value with centisecond

Comment: Why does your "Duration" column go up by a thousandth of a second if the data are all in hundredths?

Comment: Thanks for your question! I don't know if I really understood what you asked, sorry. So, the duration should be cumulative. For the first 100 packets, we have a duration of 00:00:00:099 . The 101st is where the first second starts. Did I answer @TimRoberts ?

Comment: But you are not counting in hundredths of a second (.010).  You are counting in thousandths (.001).   If the different between 196 and 197 is a hundredth, then the time in 197 should be `00:00:00.010`, not `00:00:00.001` as you have.  Is the data actually at 1000Hz?

Comment: Oh, you're totally right @TimRoberts !!!!
Ok, so I know that 100packets = 1sec (the equivalent of 1Hz, right?). My logic was: 100packets=1sec, so, each packet is the equivalent of 0.01sec (100Hz).
I know that when I reach out the 100th, a new second is starting.

So we should be counting packet after packet, so `0.01` after `0.01` and not `0.001` after `0.001`. You're right! I made the same mistake on my excel sheet too.

Thanks for the catch! (and please, correct me if I'm wrong!)